# Create a wallet with ethereum node

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

If I install the ethereum node on the server, I can create a wallet through it.
Now, if I send a transaction from this wallet, do I still have to pay the fee?

In the past, someone told me that if you have a node of a blockchain network on your server, you will no longer need to pay fee for its transactions.
I want to know if this is right or wrong

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you still have to pay the gas fee.

Your fees may be limited by avoiding the use of a 3rd party exchange, however you are still going to face gas fees.

The gas fee is compensation to reimburse those with systems that are mining today, and will shift to those that are staking in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).